# My AppleID password is suddenly not being accepted for Xcode 7.1.1 or Application Loader 3

Tags: xcode, xcode7, apple-id

I originally upgraded to Xcode 7.1.1 without incident, but since the iTunes Connect portal upgrade yesterday (November 12th) I encountered problems doing TestFlight archives.  I further encountered problems logging into Application Loader 3.1.

This was working fine the afternoon of November 12th, before the iTunes Connect upgrade.  Looks like Apple has enabled some additional security.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

After some investigation the problem was, in my situation, that if you had your AppleID setup for two factor authentication, Apple is now requiring an app specific password to be used with Xcode and Application Loader since this new iTunes Connect upgrade.  Neither tool will take your regular AppleID password on the account under preferences anymore.

The information on how to add such passwords onto your AppleID account is at this Apple support link [Setup application specific passwords for an AppleID](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204397)

Once I used the app-specific password instead of my AppleID password, Xcode 7.1.1 and Application Loader 3.1 was happy and completed my archive validation and export and submission for TestFlight as usual.

Comment: Interestingly, Xcode won’t accept app-specific password on El Capitan. This seems intentional, see point 5. [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/AddingYourAccounttoXcode/AddingYourAccounttoXcode.html).

Comment: My problem is that Application Loader still won't even accept the application-specific password I generated.

Comment: It looks like I had to assign my account to be Team Agent to get this to work.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54463009/267702

Answer (score 2):

Log in to https://appleid.apple.com and enter your 2FA code.
Then in the Security section on the bottom right area, you'll see:

**APP-SPECIFIC PASSWORDS**
Generate Password...

Click the link to create an app-specific password.

Type in a name for whatever application you are using. Ex. Xcode Application Loader.

Copy the app-specific password.

Enter the password into the Application Loader.

Answer (score 1):

Try to login to https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/

If you can't, ask for the person in your company that enrolled the Apple Dev Program to try and add you as App Manager

After that probably the login in application loader will work (at least worked for me!)

Comment: And even if you can login to appstoreconnect.apple.com and on my apps click you redirected to developer.apple.com then ask to add your account role to appstoreconnect.apple.com also.

Answer (score 1):

Great

AppleID setup for two factor authentication, Apple is now requiring an app specific password to be used with Xcode and Application Loader since this new iTunes Connect upgrade.

:$