# Application Loader - your apple id or password was entered incorrectly - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, application-loader

I am trying to upload an app on iTunes Store, I have not enrolled in **apple developer account** but my client give admin access to me as he has a developer account. I am trying to upload via **Application Loader**.
I tried to signin with the app-specific password but
I keep getting the error:

> "Your Apple ID or password was entered incorrectly"

even though I am 100% certain that my credentials are correct.

After resetting my password, the problem persists.
is anything wrong?

Comment: I am using application loader that comes with Xcode, from open developer tool->Application Loader

Comment: but if I tried with my password it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem while I was using my own Apple ID account.  Although I was a team member and admin, Application Loader refused to accept my password until I assigned my account to be the Team Agent.